# Antlr v4 thread-safe mode

Tags: go, thread-safety, antlr4

I wrote my code like this:

1. Firstly I create routines pool with ants:

```golang
var pool, _ = ants.NewPoolWithFunc(5, func(commitDiff interface{}) {
    AnalyzeCommitDiff(commitDiff.(diffParsedType))
})
```

*The function AnalyzeCommitDiff() contains my antlr_analysis function

2. Then I wrote these:

```golang
var (
    lexerPool *sync.Pool = &sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        return javaparser.NewJavaLexer(nil)
    }}
    parserPool *sync.Pool = &sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        return javaparser.NewJavaParser(nil)
    }}
    newTreeShapeListener *sync.Pool = &sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        return new(TreeShapeListener)
    }}
)

func executeJava(diffText string) javaparser.AnalysisInfoType {

    input := antlr.NewInputStream(diffText)


    lexer := lexerPool.Get().(*javaparser.JavaLexer)
    defer lexerPool.Put(lexer)
    lexer.SetInputStream(input)

    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, 0)

    p := parserPool.Get().(*javaparser.JavaParser)
    defer parserPool.Put(p)
    p.SetTokenStream(stream)

    //p.AddErrorListener(antlr.NewDiagnosticErrorListener(true))

    p.BuildParseTrees = true

    p.GetInterpreter().SetPredictionMode(antlr.PredictionModeSLL)

    tree := p.CompilationUnit()

    listener := newTreeShapeListener.Get().(*TreeShapeListener)
    defer newTreeShapeListener.Put(listener)

    antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk(listener, tree)
    return javaparser.Infos
}
```

But there's issue obviously because of not thread-safe.
How can I make my code thread-safe?
Can anyone give me an example for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread pools won't work with ANTLR4. For performance reasons there's no extra thread handling, except for one place where the shared DFA is accessed by a parser or lexer.

So, the only way you can use threads is to associate a lexer/parser instance to a thread and access that only from this single thread. Use a dedicated thread per parser instance and never share lexers/parser between threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really help reduce my confusion!

Comment: @MattKevin If you find my answer helpful, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left.